# Lua global __newindex called only once

Tags: lua, lua-table

Working through the Lua exercises in 7 More Languages in 7 Weeks and getting caught on a metatables problem.

The challenge is to overload the + operator in order to be able to concatenate tables (as though they were arrays).

```
{ 1, 2, 3 } + { 4, 5, 6 } -- { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
```

So I tried to use the `__add` metamethod and created a metatable to host it.

```
local mt = {
  __add = function(lhs, rhs)
    return concatenate(lhs, rhs)
  done
}
```

I mistakenly tried to set this metatable on the global table, but this obviously doesn't propagate down to all other tables.

In an attempt to add it to all created tables, I created a separate metatable on `_G` which would use the `__newindex` metamethod, then set the original metatable every `__newindex` was activated.

```
setmetatable(_G, {
  __newindex = function(array, index)
    setmetatable(array, mt)
  end
})
```

However, this didn't work:

```
a1 = { 1, 2, 3 }
a2 = { 4, 5, 6 }
a1 + a2
```

And resulted in the following error: `attempt to perform arithmetic on global 'a1' (a nil value)`

So I threw a print statement into the global metatable to see whether it was actually being called:

```
setmetatable(_G, {
  __newindex = function(array, index)
    print('new table ' .. index)
    setmetatable(array, mt)
  end
})
```

This only ever prints the first table to be created:

```
a1 = { 1, 2, 3 }
a2 = { 4, 5, 6 }
a3 = { 4, 5, 6 }
a4 = { 4, 5, 6 }
```

Results in:

```
new table a1
```

I expect I am accidentally overriding something, because when I remove the call to `setmetatable`

```
setmetatable(_G, {
  __newindex = function(array, index)
    print('new table ' .. index)
    --setmetatable(array, mt)
  end
})
```

It prints all entries as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
setmetatable(_G, {
    __newindex = function(array, index)
        print('new table ' .. index)
        setmetatable(array, mt)
    end
})
```

When you do `a1 = { 1, 2, 3 }` then `__newindex` is going to be called with with `array` being `_G` and `index` being 'a1'. Then calling `setmetatable(array, mt)` is going to change the metatable of `_G`, undoing the effect of the original `setmetatable` call.

You probably want something more like:

```
setmetatable(_G, {
    __newindex = function(array, index)
        setmetatable(array[index], mt)
    end
})
```

But there's another problem because now the original effect of the assignment no longer takes place. `__newindex` is called instead, so `a1` remains a nil value.

You could try `array[index] = value` within the `__newindex` function but this will call the same `__newindex` again. Instead, use `rawset`:

```
setmetatable(_G, {
  __newindex = function(array, index, value)
    rawset(array, index, value)
    setmetatable(array[index], mt)
  end
})
```

Note that `__newindex` takes 3 parameters.

Now, what happens when you assign a non-table to a global like `b = 1`?

Comment: Thanks. That clears it up well. But I was wondering, would it not be possible to use `value` instead of `array[index]` in the last example?

Comment: Also in response to your last point: I guess it's worth wrapping the setmetatable in a type check, in order to prevent non-table types getting clobbered?

Comment: @DanPrince A type check would be good, and you're right: `value` is probably better to avoid the lookup.